# Spring: scope linked to invocation method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, scope

I have a general question about Spring but which is a bit difficult to explain. So I will describe the situation I'm facing in order to make it easier to understand.

I have a simple **@Singleton** service that has a **single method**. I would like to use some helper classes to help me.

**Every time the single method is called**, I would like to be able to **instantiate a new team of helper classes**. As they need to work together, these classes need **references to each other**. But I don't want to construct them by myself. Once the method of the service returns, the helper instances can be GC.

Is it possible to use Spring to create a small team of helper classes all scoped to the call of the method in the @Singleton class ?

Comment: Yup, this is a classic case for @Prototype.

Comment: I agree that the Singleton will have references to the scoped beans. But I would also like to know if the scoped bean can have injected references to the other scoped beans.